# fixing a commit message that isn't the last commit

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push, git-amend, commit-message

I make a mistake in my commit message in GitHub. what I have done

I navigated to the directory where I wanted its commit message to change.

To make vs code my default editor I ran this: git config --global core.editor "code --wait"

afterwards, I ran this in other to edit my commit message: git commit --amend

But vscode keeps opening the last committed message instead of the want I want to edit.

how can I edit the commit message of my choice?